# Linker/Compiler Error when trying to link curl library

Tags: c++, curl, linker, libraries

I have both the release and debug library files as well as all the curl header files in a folder which is in the same directory as the rest of my C++ project. I'm using VS Code and it yields no errors in the code itself. I compiled with

```
g++ <file1> <file2> -lcurl
```

And curl is the name I have for the folder. The error I'm getting is

```
<very long default bath>/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcurl
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried editing the include path to my current directory in the json settings like so:

```
"C_Cpp.default.includePath": ["C:/Users/<me>/<project folder which also holds curl folder>/**"]
```

But I am still getting the same error. I'm new to linking and macros and stuff so perhaps I didn't define
the library correctly in my header file? Here's what that looks like.

```
#define CURL_STATICLIB

#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include "curl/curl.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#pragma comment (lib, "curl/libcurl_a_debug.lib")
#else
#pragma comment (lib, "curl/libcurl_a.lib")
#endif
```

I saw something that said I may need to include the default path as well as my desired path in the json settings, but I can't find the default include path in my files even by searching and the console only prints out half the path with ... in between most of it.

This probably has a simple fix but I'm completely new to linking in C++ so I would greatly appreciate any help and suggestions.

Comment: #pragma comment lib is used in VC++, I'm not sure If gcc would understand it.

Comment: I'm not familar with lib curl (or VSCode) but one thing that strikes me about your post is that you don't seem to know the correct name of your library. The first command implies a library called `libcurl.a` but the second states it's called either `libcurl_a_debug.lib` or `libcurl_a.lib`. Obviously you need to work out what the library you are trying to link with is actually called.

Comment: And to back up what Michael says `#pragma comment` is a VC++ feature, it's not going to work with g++.

Comment: `<very long default bath>` That made me smile

Comment: You need to pass the curl library path to gcc with the `-L` argument

Comment: @john  thanks for the input. Is there a different preprocessor directive I should use for g++? I really hate dealing with visual studio configurations unless I have to.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis you too ^

Comment: @MWilbon9 I'm not aware of any g++ preprocessor command that adds libraries to be linked. That's rather a unique featire of VC++ I think. For g++ you need to find the correct options to add to the complation/linking command. As Alan Birtles says what you are probably missing is the -L option to tell the linker where to find the curl library.

Comment: @MWilbon9 The other option would be instead of installing curl in your project directory (which is a bit odd) to install it in one of the places that g++ looks for headers and libraries as standard. That way you don't have to give g++ any additional information to find curl.

Comment: @john I'd thought about that but just didn't know how to find the default include path. But I just found it and added all of the header files and even the lib files to the folder (I know it's the right folder because it has the headers for stdio and string and stuff). When I compile without -lcurl I get a bunch of undefined references, and with -lcurl I it still cannot find -lcurl. Does it possibly have anything to do with the version of the library (32 vs 64 bit)? Or maybe this isn't the correct path (C:/MinGW/include)? I really appreciate you taking the time to answer.

Comment: The correct path for headers is not the same as the correct path for libraries. I don't currently have MinGW installed but I imagine the path for libraries is C:/MinGW/lib. 32 bit vs 64 bit is also another possibility. Any library that isn't the correct number of bits will be ignored.

Comment: @john I've tried it all but it just keeps yielding the same error I'll just keep moving stuff around and hopefully it'll work eventually. Thanks for the help.